# Moving a font awesome icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

here's my first post on stackoverflow :)
I'm a web-design student, pretty noob but so enthusiastic. I was trying to make a website using bootstrap and font-awesome icons, but i don't know how to move "a little bit" one of those icons. My code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    <h4 class="service-heading">Lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
</div>
```

As you see here [http://imgur.com/zWwXnN2](https://imgur.com/zWwXnN2) would be nice if i can move a the pencil icon, a little bit to the right. Is it possible?
Thank you so much

Alessandro

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you trying to align the object more to the right?  Or are you trying to move the object with animation to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the font-awesome.css file to give it more style instructions. In this case, you're looking for the line in that file that controls the pencil icon. You can do something like this:

```
.fa-edit:before,
.fa-pencil-square-o:before {
  content: "\f044";
  *margin-left: 8px;*
}
```

Play around with the margin value to get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: i've tried but nothing seems changing :( 
http://imgur.com/5n9V5rs
i've put 10 or 100px but that icons still doesn't moving o.O

Comment: DONE! i've tried to modify the same item but in the font-awesome.min.css and everything works great! why does there is this difference? Anyway, thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I've tried to do the same thing with another icon: code.
Here, it doesn't work, neither in min.css and in the classic font--awesome.css
.fa-code:before{content:"\f121";margin-bottom:10px;}

Comment: The .min version of the CSS is a minified version. Depending on how your site is setup, and how the minified files are being generated will determine which file you would need to edit. It sounds like you found the right one to edit, based on your having success with the pencil icon. What is it you're trying to do with the code icon?

Comment: Hi @khilley , thank your for your answer! The fact is that you can move those icons only in 2 directions, not in every one :) you can give it a try in one second, just download here the template http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/ and try to move in every directions those font-awesome icons in the services section!